# javascript holiday validation

Tags: javascript, validation, date

I want to validate the first field and show content in other. Check date and show description.

My script is working except when I introduce **var Date**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#holidayDate').datepicker();
    var availableTags = ["New years Day", "Martin Luther King Day", "Groundhog Day", "Valentine's Day", "Washington's Birthday",
        "Easter", "Earth Day", "National Arbor Day", "Mother's Day", "Memorial Day", "Flag Day", "Father's Day", "Independence Day",
        "Labor Day", "Columbus Day", "Halloween", "Veterans Day", "Thanksgiving Day", "Pearl Harbor Remembrance Day", "Christmas Day"
    ];
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
    var Date = [Date().january().third().monday(), Date().february().third().monday()];
    $('#holidayDate').change(function () {
        var dateString = $(this).val().substring(0, 5);
        switch (dateString) {
        case '01/01':
            res = availableTags[0];
            break;
        case Date[0]:
            res = availableTags[1];
            break;
        case '02/02':
            res = availableTags[2];
            break;
        case '02/14':
            res = availableTags[3];
            break;
        case Date[1]:
            res = availableTags[4];
            break;
        case '04/22':
            res = availableTags[6];
            break;
        case '06/14':
            res = availableTags[10];
            break;
        case '07/04':
            res = availableTags[12];
            break;
        case '10/31':
            res = availableTags[15];
            break;
        case '11/11':
            res = availableTags[16];
            break;
        case '12/07':
            res = availableTags[18];
            break;
        case '12/25':
            res = availableTags[19];
            break;
        }
        $('#tags').val(res);
    });
});
```

Comment: I rolled-back your question to its initial state so there is some context. The updated version didn't make any sense without the initial question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a reserved word (Date).

Set it to something like

```
var myDate = [Date().january().third().monday(),Date().february().third().monday()];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the builtin Date object when you declare a variable called Date. Rename your variable to something else.